# Function to remove access to Third-party apps & services

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to remove access to Third-party apps & services with a function from App Script?

From the same Spreadsheet that requested access, to run scripts.

I would like to run a script (function) to remove access for that spreadsheet,  instead of going to Google Account > Data & privacy > Third-party apps & services

to show what I need, I will show the entire process from request access to remove it

[image: Autorization required]

allowing script to run

[image: Allow]

and to revoke, you would need to go to:

Google Account > Third-party apps & services

[image: Third-party apps & services]

and individually

[image: keeptrack]

remove access

[image: removeaccess]

searching I found how to remove editors,  etc but not what I was looking for or what seems to be deprecated function like getAuthorization()

```
function revokeAccessToSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheetId = ss.getId();

  var authorization = ScriptApp.getAuthorization(currentSheetId);

  authorization.revoke();
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but perhaps [invalidateAuth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateauth) is what you need?

Comment: yea worked as  I wanted,  thanks, sometimes searching is hard if you don't know what to look for, so post as a reply then I can flag as answer

Comment: Completely understand, I posted my answer, feel free to flag it when you get a chance, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to an answer per the comments.

To invalidate authentication programmatically, you can use [invalidateAuth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateauth).

Note that this invalidates all auth on a given file wholesale.