# Function to remove access to Third-party apps & services by SheetID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

following my previous post [Function to remove access to Third-party apps & services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76755541/function-to-remove-access-to-third-party-apps-services)

Now , I'm  trying to revoke access by a list of IDs i have stored

With something like:

```
function revokeAccessBtSheetID() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('REVOKE');

  var range = sheet.getRange('B2:B' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();

  values.forEach(row => {
    var sheetId = row[0];
    if (sheetId) {
      var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
      if (authInfo) {
        ScriptApp.invalidateAuth();
        Logger.log(`Access revoked successfully for sheet ID: ${sheetId}`);
      } else {
        Logger.log(`Sheet ID ${sheetId} is not authorized or access has already been revoked.`);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

but actually passing and using sheetId, but i couldn't find a way to do that

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm worried that your goal cannot be directly achieved in the current specification. So, I proposed a workaround. But, I'm not sure whether this workaround is included in your expected direction. So, when my workaround was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: indeed, I thank you for your time and work to suggest a workaround, but as i feared, there isnt a way to archive what I intended, it would be faster and easier to  manually delete everything, one by one, but im sure your suggestion is the probably the only or best way,  so i marked as answered, as other users might need it, i really appreciate your help,  trying to solve my issue with that workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that `ScriptApp` can use for the current Google Apps Script project. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateauth) So, I think that `ScriptApp.invalidateAuth()` can be used for the current Google Apps Script project. If you want to remove the authorization of another Google Apps Script project, it is required to use the access token instead of Class ScriptApp. [Ref (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/05/23/remove-third-party-apps-with-account-access-using-google-apps-script/)

And, unfortunately, I cannot know `IDs` of `by a list of IDs i have stored` from your question. If your `IDs` are the Spreadsheet IDs, unfortunately, the file ID of the container-bound script cannot be directly retrieved. By this, I'm worried that your goal might be difficult to directly achieved.

From this situation, in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround. If you are required to achieve this, as a workaround, how about the following flow?

#### Flow of workaround:

1. Put the following script to each Google Apps Script project you want to remove the authorization.

   ```js
   const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
   ```
2. Deploy Web Apps as `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Only myself`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) And, retrieve Web Apps URL. In this case, you can also use Web Apps URL of the developer move.
3. At the main Google Apps Script project (this is different from the above Google Apps Script project. All authorizations are removed using this script.), please copy and paste the following script.

   ```js
   function myFunction() {
     // Please set the Web Apps URLs.
     const webAppsUrls = ["https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId1}/dev","https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId2}/dev",,,];

     const accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
     webAppsUrls.forEach(url => {
       const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
       if (!(/^<!DOCTYPE html>/).test(res.getContentText())) {
         const url2 = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=${res.getContentText()}`;
         const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2);
         console.log(res2.getResponseCode());
       }
     });
   }
   ```
4. Run `myFunction()`. By this, the authorizations of all Google Apps Script projects in `webAppsUrls` are removed.

#### References:

- [invalidateAuth()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateauth)
- [Remove Third-party Apps with Account Access using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/05/23/remove-third-party-apps-with-account-access-using-google-apps-script/)
- [Revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke)

Comment: indeed, I have SS id that i export  to a central sheet from  each of my 250~ sheets,  that once a year i update, formulas,  scripts,  etc import data from old  ones ,then I delete the old SS need to do the same for those leftover access permissions, I wanted to do something more streamlined than manually deleting everything,   but i didnt know it wasnt related to sheet id, is there a way to to  make it kinda automated for my next year update,  i mean, deploying, storing and exporting that info needed?

Comment: @Bruno Carvalho Thank you for replying. In the current stage, the authorization of Google Apps Script project "A" cannot be directly removed from Google Apps Script project "B". It seems that the method for removing the authorization using the access token might be the current workaround.

Comment: @Bruno Carvalho About `is there a way to to make it kinda automated for my next year update, i mean, deploying, storing and exporting that info needed?`, in this case, first, the script of `const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());` is put into each Google Apps Script project and retrieve the Web Apps URL. And, when you revoke the authorization of all project, when you run `myFunction`, it can be achieved.